# Density graph using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I created a craps simulator and generated some data as a result. I'm looking at the probability of wins vs losses given the number of rolls. Here's the first 25 results of my data, the rest looks exactly the same (just 50,000 rows long):

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to create a density graph with my data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=rollCount, fill = winOrLoss)) + 
    #geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, position = "identity", alpha=0.6) +
    scale_y_sqrt() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1, 32), breaks=1:32) +
    labs(title="Roll Count Histogram", x="Roll Count", y="Count") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0)) +
    geom_density()
```

and here's the resulting graph:

[image]

My hope is that the density graph looked something like this:

[image]

My main questions is how I can get it to be much more smooth instead of the up and down it currently looks like. Do I need to do something to my data before I put it in the graph? I just put it into a data frame with `df <- data.frame(rollCount, winOrLoss)` and let `ggplot` take care of the rest.

Comment: You need to adjust the width for the kernel density window. See example for `adjust` parameter [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_density.html). The default value does not suit your scale, because it's discrete, not continuous.

Comment: @tonytonov that was exactly what I was missing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a discrete distribution. `stat_density` assumes a continuous distribution. Use `geom_histogram` instead:

```
set.seed(42)
rollCount <- sample(1:20, 50, TRUE, prob = 20:1)
winOrLoss <- sample(c("W", "L"), 50, TRUE)
DF <- data.frame(rollCount, winOrLoss)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x=rollCount, fill = winOrLoss)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, position = "identity", alpha=0.6, 
                 aes(y = ..density..))
```

[image: resulting plot]